# Why does read() not work with 'w+' or 'r+' mode in open() function python

Tags: python, text-files

When ever I use the open with the 'r+' or the 'w+' parameters, It doesn't want to read the text file.

**Inside Text Document:**

`hello`

**Python Code Examples:**

code:

```py
with open(file_name, 'r') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

output:

```
hello
```

code:

```py
with open(file_name, 'r+') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

output:

code:

```py
with open(file_name, 'w+') as o:
    o.write('hello')
    print(o.read())
```

output:

I also tried setting `o.read()` as a variable and then printing it, but there still was no output. If someone could please tell me why this happens, that would be great.

Comment: `r+` doesn't truncate the file; `w+` does. Your examples suggest you are using `w+`, not `r+`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. Also make sure to recreate (make sure it's not empty) the file between runs (as the 3rd one (*r+*) might be influenced by the previous).

Comment: Neither is generally useful with text files, as you can't usefully insert arbitrary text strings into a text file while reading it, only overwrite portions of it.

Comment: `w` and `w+` truncates the file. So you're reading a file with no lines.

Comment: You might have used this in another order. If you open the file with "w" it will be empty. So I assume you did that before using "r+" because the "r+" version should print the file contents. If this does not print anything the file is actually empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

outputs ***hello***, as you say.

```
with open(file_name, 'r+') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

outputs ***hello*** as well.  I don't know why you say that it outputs nothing.

```
with open(file_name, 'w+') as o:
    o.write('hello')
    print(o.read())
```

outputs nothing because 'w+' tosses out the current contents of the file, and then after you write ***hello*** to the file, the file pointer is at the end of the file, and the read attempts to read from that point.  To read what you've written, you need to seek back to the start of the file first:

```
with open(file_name, 'w+') as o:
    o.write('hello')
    o.seek(0)
    print(o.read())
```

prints:

```
hello
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

Outputs `hello` because the file is opened for reading

```
with open(file_name, 'r+') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

Also outputs `hello` because the file is still opened for reading

```
with open(file_name, 'w+') as o:
    print(o.read())
```

Outputs nothing becuase the file is truncated.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open for more details.

Comment: I actually had a "o,write('hello')" before the "print(o.read())" statement in my original program and it still didn't work

Comment: @MaxWerner After you write to a file, the file pointer is at the *end* of what you just wrote; you'd have to "rewind" using `o.seek` to read the new data.